# UFW blocks local network routed to net_gateway by OpenVPN

Tags: openvpn, ufw

I'm trying to set up a connection on Ubuntu 22.04 to a nordvpn OpenVPN server with a kill-switch using `ufw`. I configured the VPN client to redirect the default gateway, but be able to communicate with local network resources with this line:

```
route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 net_gateway
```

Without `ufw` enabled, local network is available, while all the other resources go through the vpn tunnel.

I tried these obvious rules to allow local net via `ufw`:

```
sudo ufw allow to 192.168.1.0/24
sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.0/24
```

Yet local network is still unavailable (while Internet, say, `8.8.8.8`, is reachable), trying to `ping 192.169.1.47 -n 1` yields this line in `/var/log/ufw.log`:

```
May 11 17:57:15 alex-Zephyrus-S17 kernel: [ 2129.829445] [UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=wlo1 SRC=192.168.1.85 DST=192.168.1.47 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=35904 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=9 SEQ=1
```

Here are my `ufw status` and `ip route`:

```
alex@alex-Zephyrus-S17:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Anywhere on nordvpntun0    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Anywhere                   ALLOW       192.168.1.0/24          
192.168.1.0/24             ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
Anywhere (v6) on nordvpntun0 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             

143.244.46.172 1194/udp    ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                          
Anywhere                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere on nordvpntun0            
Anywhere (v6)              ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6) on nordvpntun0 

alex@alex-Zephyrus-S17:~$ ip route
default via 10.8.3.1 dev nordvpntun0 
10.8.3.0/24 dev nordvpntun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.3.6 
143.244.46.172 via 192.168.1.1 dev wlo1 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlo1 scope link metric 1000 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.1.1 dev wlo1 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlo1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.85 metric 600
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error I found the correct `ufw` rule:

```
sudo ufw allow out on wlo1 from 192.168.1.0/24 to 192.168.1.0/24
```

This makes local network accessible via wifi (`wlo1`), would need another rule  for access via ethernet, like

```
sudo ufw allow out on eth0 from 192.168.1.0/24 to 192.168.1.0/24
```

Comment: so openvpn does not have a setting to setup kill switch? it has to be rocket science with ufw???

Comment: @uberrebu Basically a kill switch is denying traffic _not_ through a given VPN tunnel, while openvpn is about giving access, not limiting it (according to openvpn developers, sorry can't find a proof link). Hence, yes, you have to do it yourself, and using `ufw` is probably the simplest solution.